# How to visualize a chord diagram or sankey graph using plotly Python?

Tags: python, plotly

I have a dataframe like this

```
ID ant_mi  inf_mi  lat_mi  post_mi
1  Yes      No      Yes      No
2  No       No      No       No
3  No       No      Yes      Yes
4  Yes      Yes     No       No
```

As you can see, one ID can have ant_mi and lat_mi at the time. Another has lat_mi and post_mi together. I need to use chord diagram  or sankey graphwith plotly and python to know which IDs have ant_mi and have lat_mi at the same time for example.

I have tried reading [this post](https://plotly.com/python/v3/filled-chord-diagram/) about chord diagram but I didn't fully get it.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

A Chord can also be created using the [D3Blocks](https://d3blocks.github.io/d3blocks/pages/html/Chord.html) library.

Install first:

```
pip install d3blocks
```

In your case you need to transform the dataset in the right shape first which can easily being done with the `adjmat2vec` functionality.

```
# Load d3blocks
from d3blocks import D3Blocks

# Initialize
d3 = D3Blocks()

# Load example data
df = d3.import_example('energy')

# Transform dataset
# df = d3.adjmat2vec(df)

# Plot
d3.chord(df, filepath='chord.html')
```

[image]